# Central limit theorem, number of rounds

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

There are four transport companies $A, B, C, D$, which transport passengers from Paris to Vienna.

Statistically $2000$ a month uses those companies' services and the probability that a person will choose company $A$ is $0,3$.

The company $A$ has a coach with $40$ places.

How many rides should company $A$ organize in order for the probability that a client will go away to another company is less than $0,01$.

Here is my approach:

Let $X(\omega) = X_1 + ... + X_n$ be the number of passengers transported monthly by $A$.

If we divide it by $40$, we will have the number of rides.

So the company $A$ needs to transport at least $0,3 \cdot 2000=600$ people with the probability at least $0,99$, that is $P(X \ge 600) \ge 0,99$.

Now we standardize the variable $X$ and get $Z = \frac{X - 0,3n}{\sqrt{0,3 \cdot 0,7 n}}$

And if I plug $X = \sqrt{0,21n}Z+0,3n$ I get $P(\sqrt{0,21n}Z+0,3n \ge 600) = P(Z \ge \frac{600-0,3n}{\sqrt{0,21n}}) = \Phi(\frac{0,3n-600}{\sqrt{0,21n}}) \ge 0,99$

So $\frac{600-0,3n}{\sqrt{0,21n}} \ge 2,33$

$0,3n + 1,06 \sqrt{n} -600 \le 0$

But the result isn't credible.

What am I doing wrong?

Could you help?

Comment: I may be missing something, but isn't the problem much simpler than all that?  The number of prospective customers is a nearly normally distributed variable with mean $2000(0.3) = 600$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{2000(0.3)(0.7)} \doteq 20.5$.  If you have $16$ rides, that will carry $640$ people, which is less than two standard deviations above the mean, so that won't work.  If you have $17$ rides, that will carry $680$ people, which is nearly four standard deviations above the mean, so that will work.  Isn't that all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have partly the right idea, but not quite. (Because I'm on
the North American side of the Atlantic, I'll be using . instead
of , in decimal fractions.)

First, just an intuitive approach. On average, you need to
accommodate 0.3(2000) = 600 passengers a week. But to
lose only a very small proportion to other companies
you will have to have capacity for somewhat more than 600.
The question is how many more.

Your weekly number of customers is a random number $X \sim Bin(n=2000, p=0.3),$
so you want to find $c$ such that $P\{X > c\} = 0.01$ or, equivalently,
$P\{X \leq c\} = 0.99$.  If you have statistical software available,
you can find $c$ exactly and directly. For example, in R, 'qbinom(.99, 2000, 0.3)'
returns 648. You would need 648/40 = 16.2 trips (busloads).
If you round up to 17, you will take care of essentially 100% of
the demand (lose no customers at all). If you round down to 16, you
will have capacity for 16*40 = 640 people, which will be adequate
97.5% of the time. (In R, 'pbinom(640, 2000, 0.3)' returns 0.9754.)

If you don't have such software available, your idea to use the
normal approximation will work: 
$$0.99 = P\{X \le c\} = P\{(X - 600)/20.5 \leq (c - 600)/20.5\} \approx
P\{Z \leq 2.326\},$$ where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable, $\sqrt{2000*.3*.7} = 20.5,$ and solving
$(c - 600)/20.5 = 2.326$ gives $c = 648.$

It seems your only mistake was to confuse the 600 customers on average
with the $n = 2000$ potential customers when attempting the normal approximation to the binomial.

Comment: @Brian Tung sent his nice brief intuitive note while I was fussing with the TeX code in my longer one.  I hope you will learn something from each.